# Perpetual Yahrtzeit

Tags: yahrtzeit

For how many years after someone has passed do you say kaddish on their Yahrtzeit.  My father and mother have both passed away, as have all their siblings. Should/can a grandchild say kaddish on the Yahrtzeit? Someone told me that there are sources that say that a Yahrtzeit "expires" after 5O years, anyone heard of that?

Comment: It looks like you can find the answer in the duplicate question, but have in mind that for practical ruling you should always ask your rabbi

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes quoted that Kadish and / or Yahrtzeit are not kept longer than 50 (not 100) years after the deceased's passing. Yet, The ספר ציץ אליעזר חלק יד' סימן עה, סעיף ב and ספר ציוני הלכה הלכות אבלות - Authored by הרב בן ציון הכהן קוק - in the name of R' Yosef Shalom Elyashiv, and R' Ovadia Yosef ספר חזון עובדיה על הלכות אבלות חלק ג' (עמודים רלז-רלח) all say that Kaddish and Yohrzeit are kept for even much longer.

Comment: I didn't find the similar question before posting.  I tried to delete now, but a message comes up that I can't delete it since others have invested time in answering. Thank you.